# BelongsToMany associations in CakePHP 3, how to keep relations and save associations in a secondary field?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need help to create a belongsToMany relation between 2 tables. I need this relation to be permanent and the "state of the relation" to be stored in an additional field in the relation table.

Here goes some background. I'm buildind a website for a restaurant.

This restaurant has a few cards (Brasserie, Gastronomique...):

**cartes**

```
id | name | description
```

Every card has many sections (Starters, Salad, Meat, Fish...). Every section may happen in multiple cards.

**cartes_rubriques**

```
id | name | description | comment
```

Cards and Sections have a `belongsToMany` relation thanks to a table

**cartes_cartes_rubriques**

```
id | carte_id | rubrique_id| order | description | comment | active (boolean)
```

I need this relation to be permanent. The relation may be temporarly removed as some sections may be seasonal but I need to keep the *order*, *description* and *comment* to be saved.

I've tried *'saveStrategy' => 'append'* but this only adds new records to cartes_cartes_rubriques.

**CartesTable.php**

```
$this->belongsToMany('Rubriques', [
    'foreignKey' => 'carte_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'rubrique_id',
    'through' => 'cartes_rubriques'
]);
```

**CartesRubriquesTable.php**

```
$this->belongsToMany('Cartes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'rubrique_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'carte_id',
    'through' => 'cartes_rubriques'
]);
```

**CartesCartesRubriquesTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Cartes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'carte_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);

$this->belongsTo('CartesRubriques', [
    'foreignKey' => 'cartes_rubrique_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

My strategy would ideally be to save theses relations and toggle *cartes_cartes_rubriques.active*.

Does this seem to be a good / possible strategy?

How can I make the toggeling on *cartes_cartes_rubriques.active*?

Do you have a better option?

Thanks for your help.
Antonio

Comment: I think it would help if you add some technical details as to in what situations exactly you plan/need to toggle that columns value, and how you plan on using it later on.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ndm

An example would be season food, like game (_gibier or chasse in  french_) that is only available in autumn. It would need to be **on** for a few weeks only.

Another example, some cards (_cartes_) may not need to display at all some categories.
As for the **how**, that's the point of my question.

Comment: I don't understand the question fully - are you asking how to change a field in the cartes_cartes_rubriques table? As in how to change _joinData?

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks for your comment. What you are suggesting is part of the problem.
Whent you deselect an option in a _select list_ stored in a _belongsToMany_ relation, the record gets deleted, therefore, losing all _joinData.
I have an _active_ field in cartes_cartes_rubriques. Upon deselection, I would like to keep the relation line and **toggle the value of _active_** in _cartes_cartes_rubriques.active_.
I hope this makes my question more understable.